# Textmate 2 scope: Increase font size for section in latex document

Tags: scope, textmate, textmatebundles

**Q: When editing a .tex file in Textmate 2: How can you print latex sections in a bigger font size?**

I added following grammar to the Latex bundle:

```
{   patterns = (
    {   begin = 'section\{';
        end = '\}';
        name = 'markup.heading.1.latex';
    },
);
}
```

And additionally I added following Setting that is applied to the newly defined `markup.heading.1.latex` scope:

```
{   fontName = 'Baskerville';
fontSize = '2.25em';
}
```

The problem: it only matches sections without a leading :

[image]

... and when I change the scope definition to the following (adding \\ in front of "section"):

```
{   patterns = (
    {   begin = '\\section\{';
        end = '\}';
        name = 'markup.heading.1.latex';
    },
);
}
```

.. the scope is not applied.

Any ideas?

Comment: I asked a similar question on tex.stackexchange due to the lack of response here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98574/textmate-2-how-can-increase-font-size-of-sections-in-the-markup-code

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is to edit the theme bundle.

The procedure to change the appearance of section in Texmate 2 is the following:

In the Bundle editor menu, select Edit bundles ....

Then select the bundle Themes.

From menu File, select New, and when prompted select Setting

Give a name to the setting.

In the Scope Selector field use meta.function.section.latex

Then you can edit the setting, for example:

```
{   
    fontName = 'Courier';
    fontSize = 36;
}
```

Then save (in the usual way, e.g, command-s).

You can repeat for other sectioning command (to identify the scope, move the cursor on the appropriate place and then use the following key combination control-shift-P)

[answer taken from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98574/textmate-2-how-can-increase-font-size-of-sections-in-the-markup-code) Please give the original author credit.